Lines of constant geodesic curvature and torsion
What is the parametrization of a curve on surface of revolution with constant geodesic torsion $\tau_g$ and constant geodesic curvature $\kappa_g$?
Special case of helix on a cylinder has constant $\tau_g$, zero $\kappa_g.$
In cylindrical coordinates I derived the relation for $\kappa_g:$
$$ \tan \gamma= {d(r \sin \psi)}/{dz}\tag 1$$
and for $\tau_g$ only its definition $(\kappa_1 -\kappa_2)\sin \psi~\cos \psi $ is available. $\psi$ is angle between meridian and curve tangent, $\gamma $ is angle between normals to the surface and curve at the point under consideration. It vanishes for geodesics when $r \sin \psi $ is the Clairaut's constant.
Proceeding with a numerical solution in particular cases would sure lead to an image, but would not be satisfactory as there is no generality.
Are such lines  are already known?
Also corresponding to 1) what is the relation for  Mongé form surface $z= f(x,y)?$
Thanks in advance for guidance leading to the same.
